# Cygwin - How to change username?

Tags: cygwin

I have Windows 2012 server which is a part of domain, is been configured to run sftp service(on port 22) with the help of cygwin.

But it takes the username as computer name+username. If it's a part of workgroup then it takes only username. I would like to understand why it is happening in this way?

Due to this issue some application doesn't read the username and throwing error. But I'm able to access the files using putty and winscp without any issue.

Help me to change the username.

Thanks.